# No mixin named media-breakpoint-down using webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, sass, mixins

No mixin named media-breakpoint-down. I am trying to compile my sass files using webpack and I am receiving this error. Any idea what causes this error ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCt2n.jpg

## my scss snippet

```
.mh-header-info {
  @include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
      display: none;
    }
    height: 35px;
    background: $primary;
    .mh-header-details {
      font-size: 13px;
      color: $white;
      padding: 5px;
```

Comment: Have you add bootstrap to your scss?

Comment: i have fixed it using @import '~bootstrap/scss/_functions';@import '~bootstrap/scss/_variables';@import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints';

Comment: now i hve new issue which is No mixin named border-radius

Comment: You will need to includes border-radius mixin as well. Better to import the whole bootstrap mixed scss `@import "bootstrap/mixins";`

Answer (score 3):

You need import bootstrap function and mixins for bootstrap 5

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

or breakpoints too in bootstrap 4

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/breakpoints";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```